# Conflict with SLF4J Implementations in Maven Project with Micronaut and Apache Beam

Tags: java, maven, apache-beam, micronaut

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a Maven project using Micronaut 4 and Apache Beam, facing an SLF4J logging issue. Despite having `logback-classic` in my dependencies, I encounter the standard SLF4J error:

```bash
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

I've tried excluding `org.slf4j` from various dependencies, but the issue persists. When I remove `beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform`, logging works correctly, suggesting a conflict. I also noticed `slf4j-simple` in the classpath, which might be causing the issue. Here's a snippet of my pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The project can be cloned from https://github.com/j1cs/logback-error. To run the project, use:

```bash
./mvnw mn:run -DskipTests=true
```

The expected log output should be:

```bash
00:14:57.306 [main] INFO  i.m.c.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment - Established active environments: [cli]
00:14:57.308 [main] INFO  i.m.c.DefaultApplicationContext$BootstrapEnvironment - Established active environments: [cli]
00:14:57.328 [main] INFO  i.m.context.DefaultBeanContext - Reading bootstrap environment configuration
```

Could someone provide insights or suggestions on resolving this SLF4J implementation conflict in this setup?

Thank you!

Comment: can you check https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BEAM/Java+Tips#JavaTips-HowdoIconfigureSLF4J??

Comment: i replaced: ch.qos.logback:logback-classic to org.slf4j:slf4j-api slf4j-jdk14 and now is showing log!

Answer (score 0):

Well replacing:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and adding `log4j2.xml` in `src/main/resources` now i can see log.

Comment: slf4j-simple:1.7.36 also works with your code. BR

Comment: yeah. in the comment section below the question i pointed that out.